# Drainage solution for pool area

Tags: drainage, pool, demolition, french-drain

I have a pool area which was filled with dirt. Side wall are intact but there were three large holes done at the bottom. During heavy rain season i see there is a water logging in the pool area as water have no way to escape (in  the side).

[image]

This was discussed in detail in an earlier post [Water logging in demolished pool area](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81326/water-logging-in-demolished-pool-area)

Now i want to create a drainage solution to it. I have two options.

Approach #1) create a contour in the middle of pool something like below and put a perforated PVC pipe  along the drainage canal.

[image]

Approach  #2) Do grading and have 3  ground drains to collect water and use the solid PVC pipe.

Approach  #3) Use both ground drain and perforated pipe. i.e hybrid approach of #1 and #2

Which of the above are preferred in this situation? I am having compacted soil in the pool area so i believe water is not getting down to the bottom area of the pool for drainage. Pool area is roughly 30'X 15'

Comment: I would recommend diverting the water away from the sunken pool using turf/ground drains and solid pipe, assuming you have the topography to allow you to bury the pipe and still provide adequate slope, and then discharge it in a lower area. I have heard (anecdotal) about buried pools pushing upwards due to displacement by water.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, Thanks for the reply.Does that mean option #2 is better? My only concern is in option #2 i can only have 2-3 ground drains and if water seeps into subsurface it will saturate the ground. Isn't perforated PVC pipe good for draining the subsurface water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can pipe the water somewhere downhill, you can use a french drain if you don't want to have a exposed trench or visible drainage grates in the middle of your yard.

A french drain is a low maintenance underground trench filled with rocks and gravel around a perforated pipe, and it is usually used to pipe the water away to a lower spot or some kind of sump pump.

They also make prefabricated french drains which is easier to install, its basically a "pipe" that you can bury and serves the same purpose without needing rocks and gravel.